# Checking if video is age restricted with v3 of YouTube API

Tags: youtube-data-api

Is there a way with v3 of the YouTube API to check if a video has an age restriction on it? Looking at the documentation I've been unable to confirm this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found something related to this,check

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

replace `VIDEO_ID` with the id of video you want to check.

**API Response**:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"mPrpS7Nrk6Ggi_P7VJ8-KsEOiIw/el3Y0P65UwM366CJD3POX-W4y0c\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"mPrpS7Nrk6Ggi_P7VJ8-KsEOiIw/Rn64PVwC0Uhr4xp41vDOqygjJ9c\"",
   "id": "VIDEO_ID",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT10M6S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "contentRating": {
     "ytRating": "ytAgeRestricted"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Check the `ytRating`, it has value `ytAgeRestricted`, means the video is age restricted.

**From Youtube-API docs**:

```
contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating : string
       A rating that YouTube uses to identify age-restricted content.
       Valid values for this property are: ytAgeRestricted
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
var myWebClient = new WebClient();
var responseString = myWebClient.DownloadString(" https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=" + videoId + "&key=your_api_key_here");

var parsedResponseString = JObject.Parse(responseString);
JToken token = parsedResponseString["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["contentRating"];

if (token != null) {
  // there is no "contentRating" so no age restriction because "ytRating", if present, would be inside of "contentRating"

}
```